# getting the value of my text area

Tags: java, swing

l know the  **`JTextArea.getText()`** to get the value and put it on String.

What I want is, if my value on my text area is like this:

```
 1
 2
 3
```

I want to put it on String like this

```
"1\n2\n3"
```

*If ever your confuse why I ask stuff. I just want to save the `"\n"` on a external file like `csv`.

Comment: use StringBuilder.append(YourString + "\n"); and at the last character trim the string

Comment: Can you provide me some example.tnx

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't already include the new line characters? Have you tried outputting the result of getText()? I think it should have \n characters in it.

Comment: yes I already try it. and "\n" create another new line on csv

Comment: do you want the newline character or do you want to actually **see** the backslash n as output? So \n -> \\n in your output?

Comment: yes thats right.  like JTextArea.setText(1\n2\n3);

and it appears on TextArea Like this

1 [new Line]

2[new Line]
3

so I want to getText this value "1\n2\n3" on my String a store it on my csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want those linebreaks to be "human readable", you should replace them:

```
String output = textArea.getText().replace("\n", "\\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
String output = textArea.getText().split("\\n");
```